# Promise { <pending> } LOG

Tags: javascript, promise

i was making meme.js file/command and i got this error idk how to resolve this problem, Can you help me?

so this is my code:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const randomPuppy = require("random-puppy");

module.exports = {
    name: "meme",
    description: "Sends an epic meme",
    execute(message) {
        const subReddits = ["dankmeme", "meme", "me_irl"];
        const random = subReddits[Math.floor(Math.random() * subReddits.length)];

        const img = await randomPuppy(random);
        console.log(img)
        const memeEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setColor("#fa0557")
          //  .setImage(`${img}`)
            .setTitle(`From /r/${random}`)
            .setURL(`https://reddit.com/r/${random}`);

        message.channel.send({ embeds: [memeEmbed] });
    }
}
```

And this is the log i got:

```
Promise { <pending> }
```

Comment: Your code as shown will not run.  You show `await randomPuppy(random)`, but `await` is NOT allowed there because it's not inside an `async` function.  So, I suspect that your real code does not have the `await` and that's why you show `Promise { <pending> }` in your console.  You have to use either `await` or `.then()` on the promise that `randomPuppy(random)` returns.

Comment: [How to access the value of a promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29516390) | [What are asynchronous functions in JavaScript? What is "async" and "await" in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62196932)

Answer (score 1):

The posted code throws a syntax error that `await` can only be used inside an async function - which `module.exports.execute' has not been declared as.

Try declaring `execute` as an async function

```
module.exports = {
    name: "meme",
    description: "Sends an epic meme",
    async execute(message) { . . .
```

If the log in the post does show

```
Promise { <pending> }
```

on the console, please update the post with necessary code to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your code as shown will not run.  You show `await randomPuppy(random)`, but `await` is NOT allowed there because it's not inside an `async` function.  So, I suspect that your real code does not have the `await` and that's why you show `Promise { <pending> }` in your console.  You have to use either `await` or `.then()` on the promise that `randomPuppy(random)` returns.

If I fix your code so that it will run by adding `async` to the `execute()` definition, then the `console.log(img)` actually works just fine:

```
const randomPuppy = require("random-puppy");

module.exports = {
    name: "meme",
    description: "Sends an epic meme",
    async execute(message) {
        const subReddits = ["dankmeme", "meme", "me_irl"];
        const random = subReddits[Math.floor(Math.random() * subReddits.length)];

        const img = await randomPuppy(random);
        console.log(img)
    }
}

module.exports.execute().then(result => {
    console.log(result);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

And, I get in my console this:

```
http://imgur.com/FFkL628.gif
done
```

So, my conclusion is that the code you posted in your question is not the code you're actually running.  This code shown here will work just fine.