# How to continue the function after fetching

Tags: javascript

I have a script currently that needed to fetch data:

```
fetch("https://data.weather.gov.hk/weatherAPI/opendata/weather.php?dataType=flw&lang=en")
.then(r => r.json())
.then(result => console.log(result))
```

If I had to continue the script, I can use these methods:

Method 1:

```
function stuff(){
   ...
   .then(result => function(){ <code> })
}
```

Method 2:

```
function stuff(){
   ...
   .then(result => fetchcont(result))
}
function fetchcont(r){
   <code>
}
```

Is there a way that this can be presented in a neater way, for example:

```
function stuff(){
   ...
   .then(result => *continue*)
   <script goes here>
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use `async`/`await`? [What are asynchronous functions in JavaScript? What is "async" and "await" in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62196932)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to use async/await instead of `.then()`.

Your code would look something like:

```js
// your function need to be async in order to use await keyword
async function stuff(){
try {
//await
const res = await fetch(url);
// next line will only execute when above fetch is complete
const json = res.json()

*Do Your other stuff here*

} catch (e) {
console.log("Err",e)
  }
}
```

[You can read more about async/await here.](https://javascript.info/async-await)

Comment: Thank you! I have really just started in Javascript and I really don't know much about await and async.