# What will be the use of async keyword after the ES2022 release?

Tags: javascript, async-await, es2022

I am just curious, as per `ES2022` release we can use top level `await` and that means we don't need to use `async` keyword to use `await`, before `es2022` release we were not allowed to write `await` without `async`.
So what will be the use of `async` keyword now? Is there are any other use cases where we can utilize `async` keyword?

Reference -
[What’s new in JavaScript after the ES2022 release](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/whats-new-in-javascript-after-the-es2022-release-de13dd091a61)

Comment: **Top level** await does not mean you no longer need to mark functions as `async` to use  `await` inside them. It only means that you can use `await` in module code.

Comment: [What are asynchronous functions in JavaScript? What is "async" and "await" in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62196932)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Top-level await does *not* replace async functions. You will still (and forever) be forbidden to do

```
const fn = () => {
  await callApi();
};
```

or anything more complicated than that, because await can only used in an async function - and permitting `await` on the top level doesn't change that.

Functions are the building blocks of modular programming. Top-level await is only there to make the syntax a bit easier - it doesn't fundamentally change the language or make functions obsolete.

Answer (score -1):

If you ever want to use await inside a function.