# node.js / javascript / SQL with async/await - not behaving synchronously

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, db2

I am trying to call function that makes SQL call and returns the data to the calling function
I am trying unsuccessfully to use async/await (promises) syntax in node.js/javascript
My function is still behaving asynchronously.

Perhaps not quite understanding how this is supposed to work.
See notes in code

```
const {dbconn, dbstmt} = require('idb-pconnector');

async function get_data(){

        const {dbconn, dbstmt} = require('idb-connector');
        const sql_stsmt = 'SELECT * FROM QIWS.QCUSTCDT';
        const conn1 = new dbconn();
        conn1.conn('*LOCAL');
        const stmt = new dbstmt(conn1);

        try {
            await stmt.exec(sql_stsmt, (x) => {
            stmt.close();
            conn1.disconn();
            conn1.close();            
            // getting expected data here..
            console.log("1..")     
            console.log("%s", JSON.stringify(x));                
            return x;
            });
        }
        catch (error) {
            return console.error(error);            
            }
    }

async function main() {
    try{
        const result = await get_data()
        console.log("2..")     
        // still coming out undefined here...
        console.log("%s", JSON.stringify(result));                
        return result;
    }
    catch(error){
        return console.error(error);            
    }
}

let data = main();
console.log("3..")     
// coming out empty {} here.
console.log("%s", JSON.stringify(data));
```

Comment: `stmt.exec()` evidently doesn't return a promise, if it did, there would be no reason to accept a callback. Since it doesn't return a promise, using `await` on it doesn't do anything. Check the documentation and see if there is a promise API. If not, you can convert the callback API to a promise yourself: [How do I convert an existing callback API to promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22519784)

Comment: ^^ Like @VLAZ says,  so you might find this useful -> https://www.npmjs.com/package/idb-pconnector

Comment: See also [async/await implicitly returns promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35302431) | [Async function returning promise, instead of value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51338277) | [Why is my asynchronous function returning Promise { <pending> } instead of a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38884522) | [[What are asynchronous functions in JavaScript? What is "async" and "await" in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62196932)

Comment: my bad, I somehow flipped from idb-pconnector to idb-connector. I put it back, but still does not work.

Comment: Now your using the promise based one, remove the callback -> `await stmt.exec(sql_stsmt, (x) => `  to `const x = await stmt.exec(sql_stsmt);`  Often API have dual purpose, and if you supply a callback it won't return a promise.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do cannot be done in JavaScript.

=== edit ===

It can be done, but it still must be done in an asynchronous function. `async and await` do not fundamentally change how promises work in JavaScript, nor it being single threaded.

Async functions return a Promise, and the only way to get the results of this promise in a non-async function is by calling `then` on the promise.

```
let data = main.then(function (result) {
  console.log("%s", JSON.stringify(result)); 
});
console.log("3..")     
// coming out empty {} here.
```

```js
var async_func = () => {
  var p = new Promise((result) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      result("foo");
    });
  });
  return p;
}

var func1 = () => {
  console.log("func1: " + async_func());
}

var func2 = () => {
  async_func().then((res) => {
    console.log("func2: " + res);
  });
}
var func3 = async () => {
  var x = await async_func();
  console.log("func3: " + x);
}

func3();
func1();
func2();
```

Comment: Not sure, but I think you might have missed the memo.  Modern JS has `async/await`, so what the OP wants can be done, but his issue is that he's not used a Promise based implementation of his idb-connector.

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap **exec** method
simple example:

```
function execWithCallback(callback: (x: number, err: Error | null) => void) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    callback(1, null)
  }, 1000)
}

async function execPromise() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    execWithCallback((x, err) => {
      if(err) return reject(err)

      return resolve(x)
    })
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lots of good ideas and readings.
Thanks to Keith and and VLAZ was able to revise. Works now.
(But, still may need some help with error trapping logic.)

```
const {Connection, Statement} = require('idb-pconnector');

async function get_data(){

        const sql_stsmt = 'SELECT * FROM QIWS.QCUSTCDT';        
        const connection = new Connection({ url: '*LOCAL' });
        const stmt = new Statement(connection);
        
        try {
            const x = await stmt.exec('SELECT * FROM QIWS.QCUSTCDT');                
            stmt.close();
            connection.disconn();
            connection.close();            
 
            return x;
        }
        catch (error) {
            return console.error(error);            
            }
    }

async function main() {
    try{
        const result = await get_data()
        console.log("log from function main()");
        console.log("%s", JSON.stringify(result));                
        // now we can present data on web page...
        // ...
    }
    catch(error){
        return console.error(error);            
    }
}

main();
```

Comment: Note: when you do -> `catch (error) { return console.error(error); }`  your basically handling the error and will not propagate down.  IOW: an error in `getData` will not be seen in `main`, in most cases these sort of catch clauses are not really needed, and should be left to some top level handler.