# What is `async*`?

Tags: javascript, symbols

[This example on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/asyncIterator) explains `Symbol.asyncIterator`.

```
 const myAsyncIterable = {
    async* [Symbol.asyncIterator]() {
        yield "hello";
        yield "async";
        yield "iteration!";
    }
};

(async () => {
    for await (const x of myAsyncIterable) {
        console.log(x);
        // expected output:
        //    "hello"
        //    "async"
        //    "iteration!"
    }
})();
```

My problem is what does `async*` mean in the code?

Comment: [generator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*)

Comment: and  [async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

Comment: `async*` is used in your example because it is an async function (see [What is the meaning of the `async` keyword?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49636379/215552) as part of a method definition in an object literal, which doesn't require the `function` keyword.

Comment: While all of the linked questions are _related_, I don't agree that this question is a duplicate of any of them. None of them address the specific use case of `async*` and `Symbol.asyncIterator`.

Comment: @HereticMonkey it's an async *generator*, not just an async function.

Comment: @VLAZ Technically, it's an async generator function. What's your point? I was continuing my comment right above that one, where I mention `function*`.

Comment: @HereticMonkey generator functions and functions are definitely not the same in terms of how they work. The terminology is not really interchangeable. And the async iterator protocol is also not just something you can say "it's just a function". Your comment *vastly* oversimplified things.

Comment: Guys I know very good async_await function and genrator function but i don't understand "async*" why * ??

Comment: For the same reason as `function*`.

Comment: Your mean "aync*" equal to "aync function* "

Comment: It's basically the same in a different context. You can't use them interchangeably. `async*` can only be used when using shorthand for creating methods on object literals or classes.

Comment: @VadimOrlov212 MDN is a wiki. Feel free to submit a modification. But your "correct code" looks an awful lot like the code I see on MDN at the link provided by the OP. It also works [in a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0wj7mpat/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example given makes use of shorthand for creating methods in object literals or classes. Consider the following object definition:

```js
const iHaveAMethod = {
  myMethod() {
    return "cool!";
  }
};
console.log(iHaveAMethod.myMethod()); // cool!
```

It also uses bracket syntax to define a method using a symbol.

```js
const iAmASymbol = Symbol("neat");
const iHaveAMethod = {
  [iAmASymbol]() {
    return "cool!";
  }
};
console.log(iHaveAMethod[iAmASymbol]()); // cool!
```

It creates a method on an object that is a generator (using the `*` syntax).

```js
const iHaveAMethod = {
  * myMethod() {
    yield "cool!";
  }
};
console.log(iHaveAMethod.myMethod().next().value); // cool!
```

Finally, it's an asynchronous method, and so is marked with `async`.

```js
const iHaveAMethod = {
  async* myMethod() {
    yield Promise.resolve("cool!");
  }
};
iHaveAMethod.myMethod().next().then(val => console.log(val.value)); // cool!
```

Combine it with the bracket syntax, and you get `async*`:

```js
const iAmASymbol = Symbol("neat");
const iHaveAMethod = {
  async* [iAmASymbol]() {
    yield Promise.resolve("cool!");
  }
};
iHaveAMethod[iAmASymbol]().next().then(val => console.log(val.value)); // cool!
```

That explains how the `async*` got on there. Async iterators and why you'd want an async generator is a whole different ball of wax.

Comment: One small nitpick, `yield Promise.resolve(value)` is the same as `yield value` in an async context. Very nice explanation otherwise.